# Limits with complex numbers and their modulus

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

If $z$ is a complex number, how would you determine the limit as $z$ tends to $0$ of $\ \frac{z^4}{|z|^4} $?

Comment: Are you assuming it has a limit?

Comment: No, I'm trying to determine if one exists - I don't think there is one though

Comment: Good, I'd write $z=re^{it}$.

Comment: So you're asking: $\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{z^4}{|z|^4}$?

Comment: If you're having trouble visualizing this function, try writing $z$ in polar form and simplifying.

Comment: Yes Joe that's what I'm asking

Comment: Leave the 4th power off for a moment...similar problem, same answer

Comment: Tends to $0$ in which direction?  You have complex number whose absolute value is $1$. $z$ as $r*e^{i\theta}$ and so $\frac {z^4}{|z^4|} = e^{i4\theta}$ and you are asking what is $\lim_{r*e^{i\theta}\to 0} e^{i4\theta}$ which is ... kind of meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking about the existence of
$$
\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{z^4}{|z|^4}.
$$

Let's first examine what happens if $z \to 0$ along the positive $x$-axis. Then, $z = x + 0i = x > 0$ and $x \to 0$, so the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^4}{x^4} = 1.
$$

Can we possibly approach along a different curve where you would get a different answer? For example, think about $\left(\sqrt{i}\right)^4 = -1$.